# Why is elasticsearch giving me results that don't match my query

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to make sure that only documents where `"relationship_type":"group"` is returned but why is `"relationship_type: "event"` being returned as well with a score similar to `"relationship_type":"group"`? Also why isn't my source filtering working?

My request on dev-tools

```
POST get-together/_search?size=5

{
  "query": {
         "match": { "relationship_type":   "group"        }
  },
  "fields": ["relationship_type"],
  "_source": false  
}
```

The response, note that I had to put a limit on the size, otherwise it was returning everything for some reason. My source isnt being filtered and the last document doesn't match my query

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 20,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "get-together",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "relationship_type" : "group",
          "name" : "Denver Clojure",
          "organizer" : [
            "Daniel",
            "Lee"
          ],
          "description" : "Group of Clojure enthusiasts from Denver who want to hack on code together and learn more about Clojure",
          "created_on" : "2012-06-15",
          "tags" : [
            "clojure",
            "denver",
            "functional programming",
            "jvm",
            "java"
          ],
          "members" : [
            "Lee",
            "Daniel",
            "Mike"
          ],
          "location_group" : "Denver, Colorado, USA"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "get-together",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "relationship_type" : "group",
          "name" : "Elasticsearch Denver",
          "organizer" : "Lee",
          "description" : "Get together to learn more about using Elasticsearch, the applications and neat things you can do with ES!",
          "created_on" : "2013-03-15",
          "tags" : [
            "denver",
            "elasticsearch",
            "big data",
            "lucene",
            "solr"
          ],
          "members" : [
            "Lee",
            "Mike"
          ],
          "location_group" : "Denver, Colorado, USA"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "get-together",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "relationship_type" : "group",
          "name" : "Elasticsearch San Francisco",
          "organizer" : "Mik",
          "description" : "Elasticsearch group for ES users of all knowledge levels",
          "created_on" : "2012-08-07",
          "tags" : [
            "elasticsearch",
            "big data",
            "lucene",
            "open source"
          ],
          "members" : [
            "Lee",
            "Igor"
          ],
          "location_group" : "San Francisco, California, USA"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "get-together",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "relationship_type" : "group",
          "name" : "Enterprise search London get-together",
          "organizer" : "Tyler",
          "description" : "Enterprise search get-togethers are an opportunity to get together with other people doing search.",
          "created_on" : "2009-11-25",
          "tags" : [
            "enterprise search",
            "apache lucene",
            "solr",
            "open source",
            "text analytics"
          ],
          "members" : [
            "Clint",
            "James"
          ],
          "location_group" : "London, England, UK"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "get-together",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "100",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_routing" : "1",
        "_source" : {
          "relationship_type" : {
            "name" : "event",
            "parent" : "1"
          },
          "host" : [
            "Lee",
            "Troy"
          ],
          "title" : "Liberator and Immutant",
          "description" : "We will discuss two different frameworks in Clojure for doing different things. Liberator is a ring-compatible web framework based on Erlang Webmachine. Immutant is an all-in-one enterprise application based on JBoss.",
          "attendees" : [
            "Lee",
            "Troy",
            "Daniel",
            "Tom"
          ],
          "date" : "2013-09-05T18:00",
          "location_event" : {
            "name" : "Stoneys Full Steam Tavern",
            "geolocation" : "39.752337,-105.00083"
          },
          "reviews" : 4
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what my mapping for the `relationship_type`field looks like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the empty line that is between the POST and the JSON query otherwise the query is not taken into account.

In Dev Tools, it should look like this:

```
POST get-together/_search?size=5
{   <---- no empty line here
  "query": {
         "match": { "relationship_type":   "group"        }
  },
  "fields": ["description"],
  "_source": false  
}
```